# xcode Picker loading subsequent components after selection

Tags: xcode, components, picker

Here's what I would like to do.  If someone knows if this is possible, and how, that would be great.  I have a picker with three components.  The second two components can change value based on which item is selected in the first component.  I need a way to know when component 1 stops moving, so I can load the other two columns.

ex:

component 1 = car brands aka: GM, Ford, etc

component 2 = car models  aka Cherokee, Cirrus, etc

component 3 = model features  aka air conditioning, 4 wheel drive, etc

So as the user selects a brand in component 1, I would then load the models for that brand in component 2, the user selects component 2, I would then load the available features for that brand/model in component 3.

...any thoughts??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use three Or "n" data source, depending upon your selection in first column change the required data source in switch case and reload.

Comment: that part I know, I was more interested in figuring out how to tell when component 1 had stopped moving and I should load the next one.

Comment: - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component will get called

Comment: I thought that was called when the user clicked a selection rather than the picker component stopped moving.  Maybe a better way to go would be to only populate the first component, let the user select, then fill the second component, let the user select then fill in the third and final component?

Comment: That will look cool and you can also try showing components one by one when user selects from first component second will show...as reload calls all delegate method careful change of return value in numberOfComponentsInPickerView  can achieve it.

Comment: actually it turns out that this method is called when the picker component stops moving as well  :)  So it works well!